# How do I make a success alert appear after correct submission in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show the user a form sent correctly alert message with javascript using bootstraps built in alerts.

When I run the code I get the object array of the values (inspecting the page at console log). what I want to do is after it is sent, to display a success alert (if it is a success).

there is test4.sj which contains the javascript code and then there is main.php which is the code for the form.

The code that I have so far is in the snippet.

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
    var that = $(this),
    type = that.attr('action'),
    data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        //console.log(value);
        var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();
        data[name] = value;
    });

    console.log(data);

    /*  $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,

        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    })*/

    return false;
})

<body>
<form method="post" class="ajax">
    <div>
        <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="lName" type="text" placeholder="Your Last Name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please share what response you are getting from the AJAX request in success callback.

Comment: First have to use `event.preventDeault();` on `$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(event) ` then all other things working as per your expectation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add hidden alert panel and show it on AJAX success.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" class="ajax">
  <div class="alert alert-success js-alert hidden" role="alert">
        Form was successfully sent!
  </div>

  ...

  <div>
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name">
  </div>

  ...

  <button type="submit" class="btn js-btn">Send</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('form').on('submit', function( event ) {
  var $form = $( this );

  event.preventDefault();
  $('.js-alert').addClass('hidden');
  $('.js-btn').button('loading');

  $.ajax({
    url: '/someurl',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function(response){
        $('.js-alert').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.js-btn').button('reset');
    }
  });
 });
```

Check the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xw63db57/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax jqXHR status and statusCode and based up on that you can write the alert code

```
success(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
   var statusCode = jqXHR.status;
   var statusText = jqXHR.statusText;
}
```